# WSO2 1.8 rejecting API call with 101508 & 303001 error codes

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm getting the below error messages interchangeably when trying to consume an API. It seems so generic error message.

Error 1:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
    <am:code>101508</am:code>
    <am:type>Status report</am:type>
    <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
    <am:description>Error in Sender</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

Error 2:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
<am:code>303001</am:code>
<am:type>Status report</am:type>
<am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
<am:description>Currently , Address endpoint : [ Name : somename-AT-sometenant--test_me_APIproductionEndpoint_0 ] [ State : SUSPENDED ]</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue.

I have done some googling and found out it's a timeout that's happening between API Manager and backend. I have tried the solution mentioned in the https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Prevent+API+Suspension link but no use.

Thanks

Comment: I see one behavior with the issue. with my GET operation, I had to pass query parameters in the URL if I pass them I'm getting the 101508 error code directly from WSO2 API Manager.. but, for testing, if I remove the query parameters it's reaching the backend API and throwing validation error saying data missing. Appreciate any help on the issue

Comment: Really appreciate any suggestion on this issue

Comment: Can you share the request (in either cURL format) in the question? Also, can you elaborate more on the behaviour a little more, please? When you are sending the Query Params it is giving you back the 101508 error code, and when it is not sent, you are getting a validation error from the Backend itself, is it correct? Also, can you share the API Manager version and a screenshot of the API Resources in the Publisher Portal in the question?

Comment: Hi Athiththan, thanks for your reply. I made some progress on the issue. I tried to consume the service from post man and it always fails with that error. if I do the same request through curl command from the server it's working some times. here is the cURL command I'm running. curl --location --request GET 'https://<<HOSTNAME>>/badge/v1?badgeReqIntId=M123456789&badgeReqId=<<RequestID>>' --header 'Authorization: Bearer <<OAuth Token>>'

Comment: If both Postman and cURL requests are the same, then you will be receiving the same response as you are observing when you are executing the cURL command. Can you also update the question with the cURL request that you use to invoke the API directly without the API Manager (direct backend request and not the request to invoke the API via the API Manager)? You can also, try enabling the WIRE log in the API Manager server and track the requests and responses from the API Manager server. Furthermore, are you seeing any errors in the API Manager when invoking the above requests?

Comment: Hi @Athiththan, thanks for your response. I have further checked the issue and found that one of the WSO2 node is the problem. Is there a checklist that i can confirm that WSO2 API manager in that node is health? I'm looking for some kind of heartbeat URL that will validate if the node is in good health or not?

Comment: There aren't any component-specific health check URLs available in the API Manager. However, you can use the endpoints mentioned in [this Doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Basic+Health+Checks#051cb824486745cf88f766f41aa2dd61) to setup a heartbeat check to the node.